# Найти нужные слова/сочетания слов в строке Python

Tags: python, list

учу Python и мне надо без импорта библиотек решить следующее задание. У меня есть строки следующие строки(их много, это пример просто):

```
new_str = "Высшее образование 1988 Московский университет"
new_str1 = "Среднее специальное образование 2000 Воронежский колледж"     
new_str2 = "Среднее образование 1997 Колледж в Туле"
new_str3 = "Неоконченное высшее 2010 в Петербурге"
```

Из этих строк мне нужны только виды образования, которые относятся к следующим категориям:
"высшее", "среднее", "среднее специальное", "неоконченное высшее"
Я делала через цикл, одно слово получается, а словосочетание - нет.
Мой код:

```py
def detect_education(arg):
    words = arg.lower()
    words = words.split(" ")
    words = words[:2]

    for i in words:
        if i == "высшее":
            return "высшее"
        elif i == "неоконченное" and i == "высшее":
            return "неоконченное высшее"
        elif i ==  "среднее" and  i == "специальное":
            return "среднее специальное"
        elif i == "среднее":
            return "среднее"
    i +=1
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту задачу.

Comment: `new_str = "Высшее образование 1988 Московский университет"` пусть есть строка, какой должен быть результат?

Comment: Переменная не может быть одновременно равна "среднее" и "специальное". Проверяйте наличие нужных слов в строке через ``in``.

Comment: образование всегда первые 2 слова с начала строки?

Comment: @Сонныйкофеман, нет, во втором примере это не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если образование всегда стоит в начале строки, то

```
def detect_education(arg):
    return " ".join(arg.lower().split(" ")[:2])
```

Comment: Спасибо, это решение мне подходит

Answer (score 0):

```
sochetanie = [
"Высшее",
"Среднее",
"Среднее специальное"
#и далее какие нужны
]
stringi = [
"Высшее образование 1988 Московский университет",
"Среднее специальное образование 2000 Воронежский колледж",     
"Среднее образование 1997 Колледж в Туле",
"Неоконченное высшее 2010 в Петербурге"
]

for soch in sochetanie:
    for strin in stringi:
          if soch in strin:
                 print("НАШЁЁЁЁЁЁЁЁЁЁЛ!!!!!!!!!!!")
```

Comment: Или вообще - так же всегда число вначале? Ну так еще проще - мы ищем в строке число (любое от 1 до 9, т.к. год с нуля у вас не может начинаться), если находим определенное число - по нему "разрезаем" строку, и у вас остается левая часть - то что вам и нужно

Comment: На самом деле мне нужны всего лишь 2 первых слова из строки - уровень образования, все остальные слова не нужны. В Вашем решении нет возврата функции - мне нужно, чтобы в каждой строке выбрался только уровень образования и отнесся к одной из групп. Строк на самом деле 44 000.В итоге у меня должны все 44 000 поделиться на 4 уровня образования.

Comment: @Victoria Yermolenko не факт, образование может быть просто "Высшее", да вот даже на мой код посмотрите. На самом деле ответ, обозначенный как правильный, не подходит. Так как чувак там предлагает взять два первых элемента (то есть два первых слова), а в вашем же примере написано, что их может быть больше. И еще раз - я не писал вам полного решения, я не для того здесь, чтобы полностью сделать вашу работу. Я показал как можно сделать - взять множество "Видов образования" и проверить каждую вашу запись на их наличие.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше время и предложенный вариант. Я пока что новичок в программировании, и возможно, неточно объяснила то, что мне нужно. В моем случае ответ, обозначенный как правильный, мне полностью подошел, к моему условию.

Answer (score 0):

во-первых проблема в `if "высшее":` - если в строке нашлось это слово, то в следующий  `elif "неоконченное" and "высшее":` вы уже не попадёте - это условие уже не будет проверяться, поэтоу мужно менять их местами. Та же ситуация и с `"среднее специальное"`.
К тому же как уж говорили: если `i` у вас, например, содержит "неоконченное", то не может содержать "высшее", т.к. это одна переменая.
Вот такой варик есть:

```
def detect_education(arg):  
    words = arg.lower()  
    words = words.split(" ")  
    words = words[:2]  
    high_edu = "высшее"
    middle_edu = "среднее"
    special_edu = "специальное"
    unfinished_edu = "неоконченное"
    if unfinished_edu in words:
        if high_edu in words:
            return unfinished_edu + " " + high_edu
        elif middle_edu in words:
            if special_edu in words:
                return unfinished_edu + " " + middle_edu + " " + special_edu
            return unfinished_edu + " " + middle_edu
    else:
        if high_edu in words:
            return high_edu
        elif middle_edu in words:
            if special_edu in words:
                return middle_edu + " " + special_edu
            return middle_edu
```